# Make sure the 'git' executable is on your PATH variable

Tags: touch, mobile

Hi am working on salesforce touch. I am trying to Install the Mobile SDK for Android but while doing it in the 
step 3. their is 'Open a command prompt in the directory where you installed the cloned repository, and run the install script from the command line: ./install.sh'
while doing this process i am getting error "There was an error getting the status of the git repository:"Make sure the 'git' executable is on your PATH variable"
can anybody help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What OS are you running? Did you have git installed?

Comment: yes i have installed it. I am using windows 7 (64 bit)

Comment: sounds like something happened to your `git` installation - an error like that strikes me as unrelated to the SDK code but more your development environment. Did you use `git clone` to get a copy of the code locally?

Comment: Can you run `git --version` from a command prompt?

Comment: no. I am new to this.

Comment: yes i run in cmd this is what i get.
c:\Users\srcloud\Downloads\forcedotcom-SalesforceMobileSDK-Android-v1.3.1-2-g641
491e\forcedotcom-SalesforceMobileSDK-Android-641491e>git --version
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: How did you install **git**? As @jordan.baucke suggested, it sounds like there is something wrong with your development environment. I'd suggest following this guide to install git & the github app on Windows. [Set Up Git](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-windows)

Comment: Actually, in looking at the instructions on [Salesforce.com Mobile SDK for Android](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android) it looks like there may be a different command for Windows. Have you tried this: (Windows users: run `cscript install.vbs` from the command line instead.)

Comment: i clone it from here : Clone the repository to your local file system by issuing the following command:
git clone
git://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android.git and download it and installed it. yes i used cscript install.vbs at that time i am getting c:\Users\srcloud\Downloads\forcedotcom-SalesforceMobileSDK-Android-v1.3.1-2-g641
491e\forcedotcom-SalesforceMobileSDK-Android-641491e>cscript install.vbs
'cscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been awhile since you posted the question, but I ran into the exact problem you encountered today:  I'm trying to install the Salesforce Mobile SDK kit for Android on Windows 7.  The guide

([http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Developing_Hybrid_Apps_with_the_Salesforce_Mobile_SDK])[1](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Developing_Hybrid_Apps_with_the_Salesforce_Mobile_SDK)

says to:

> Clone the SalesforceMobileSDK-Android project from GitHub:
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android.git
> ```

And you have to do this in `Powershell` (**not** `cmd`).

Then it says:

> Windows
>   ------- Run the install script from the *Windows command line*:
>
> ```
> cd SalesforceMobileSDK-Android
> cscript install.vbs
> ```

So I go to `cmd`, fumble around for a bit finding my `GitHub\SalesforceMobileSDK-Android` directory.  When I try to `cscript install.vbs`, it says:

> There was an error getting the status of the git repository: '' Make sure the
>      'git' executable is on your PATH variable.

So I go to change my `PATH` variable, but I can't find anything like `*--something--*\Git\bin` to point to.  Then I realized, it's trying to use the `git` executable.

**The solution is** to do everything in `Powershell`.  That is, in `Powershell`:

Go to your directory and

```
cscript install.vbs
```

and volia!

Answer (score 0):

The question is long long time ago..But I'm posting this answer since I have faced the same issue and was able to resolve the issue.


After installing **GIT**, simply set the *PATH** in your environment variables. This [link](http://blog.countableset.ch/2012/06/07/adding-git-to-windows-7-path/) will help you. Open new Command prompt and retry.